# Using a Custom login page with FBA, why does the manual change work but not the CA UI?

Tags: claims-based-auth, web-config

Is there a way to use a Custom Sign In URL with FBA?  Currently we let the default URL be used when setting up the web applications and on deployments update the web.config files with our Custom URL.  When we've tried adding in our Custom URL through the CA UI and then try to login the page never loads.  The web server seems to consistently redirect, checking with Fiddler I can see the login page is consistently giving a 302 redirect to an https version, which is the way the login works when the web.config is manually edited.

Doing a diff with the web.config files there are no real differences between them, so it feels like there is something else that gets changed when the login url is changed through the UI and is not updated manually.  Does anyone have any experience with the way the CA UI modifies the Customer Login URL and if there are changes that happen somewhere outside the web.config when the URL is changed?

What we edit is the following:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="/_layouts/app/login/loginclaims.aspx" timeout="60" domain="corp.com" />
</authentication>
```

This works out well when done manually, but when I put the login URL in the CA UI it appears the same in the web.config, yet when trying to login the page never loads.  I've not yet been able to determine what the difference is in how the changes are seen since the web.config's are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've set this up a few times and haven't had issue with the custom URL through CA. Check out my blog post on it, http://davidlozzi.com/2011/07/15/sharepoint-2010-create-unique-login-page-with-forms-based-authentication/, did you do similar?

Comment: Yes, that worked for us.  Part of the problem we found was anytime we made a change in the CAUI it updated the web.configs with whatever was set up.  In our case, with no default URL, it made that change for us without us wanting it.  So this is a good cover.